# Adding item to combobox in Delphi XE4 and Devexpress VCL 13.1

Tags: delphi, devexpress, delphi-xe4

I have following code:

```
var
cbMyCombo: TcxLookupComboBox;
```

I have a dataset which has following query:

```
SELECT ID, NAME from MYTABLE;
```

This query works fine.

Now I have done binding in cbMyCombo in DFM file as following:

```
object cbMyCombo: TcxLookupComboBox
  Properties.KeyFieldNames = 'ID'
  Properties.ListColumns = <
    item
      FieldName = 'NAME'
    end>
end
```

It works fine and combobox is binded. My problem is, nothing is selected by default. I want that initially combobox should contain **"View All"** option.

I am trying like this:

```
cbMyCombo.Text := 'View All'
```

But, this is not setting anything because "View All" is not the part of the list which I have binded to it. I want to manually add **"View All"** as `FieldName` and **0** as `KeyFieldName` and this should be selected by default. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the `'View all', 0` row to your dataset and set the `EditValue` of your combobox to 0 in your intialization.

Comment: Yes, I did like this. I modified my query.